# Numpy ndarray slicing with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am having trouble understanding the reason behind a numpy broadcasting error when trying to slice an ndarray along separate dimensions using multiple slicing arrays.
I am trying to slice `data` ndarray (100, 306, 481) along the first and second dimensions using an index array `picks`  e.g., np.arange(2, 306, 3) and a boolean array `mask`, where `mask.shape` is (481,) of which 361 elements are `True`.

`data[:, picks, mask]` returns

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast
>   together with shapes (102,) (361,)

However `data[:, :, mask]`, `data[:, picks, :]`, and `data[:, :10, mask]` work as expected.

How does broadcasting work in this case? and what is a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: If you want a slice of shape `(100, len(picks), len(mask))`, you may use `data[:, picks[:, np.newaxis], mask]`. You can not broadcast arrays with shapes of `(m,)` and `(n,)`, but can do with `(m, 1)` and `(n,)`.

Comment: You may also want to check the function `np.ix_` . Above is equivalent to `data[np.ix_(arange(100), picks, mask)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

```
data[:, :, mask]  => (100, 306, 361) 
data[:, :10, mask] => (100, 10, 361)
data[:, picks, :] => (100, 102, 481)
```

If `picks` had (361,) elements then

```
data[:, picks, mask] => (100, 361)  # I think :)
```

Think of `picks` matching `np.where(mask)`

But to index in separate dimensions, `picks` has to be a column vector, so (102,1) broadcasts with (1, 361) to produce a (102,361) selection

```
data[:, picks[:,None], mask] => (100, 102, 361) # again I need to test
```

So creating some test arrays:

```
In [253]: data=np.ones((100,306,481))
In [254]: picks=np.arange(2,306,3)
In [255]: mask=np.zeros(481,bool)
In [256]: mask[:361]=True
In [257]: data[:, picks[:,None],mask].shape
Out[257]: (100, 102, 361)
```

the arange could be replaced with a slice

```
In [259]: data[:, 2::3, mask].shape
Out[259]: (100, 102, 361)
```

`ix_` is handy in this case

```
In [268]: I,J=np.ix_(picks,mask)
In [269]: I.shape
Out[269]: (102, 1)
In [270]: J.shape
Out[270]: (1, 361)
In [271]: data[:,I,J].shape
Out[271]: (100, 102, 361)
```